# Update only one non-ppa repository

Tags: apt, updates

I have just added the Mate Desktop repository with this command:
`sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://packages.mate-desktop.org/repo/ubuntu quantal main"`

I have quite a few repositories installed, and running `sudo apt-get update` can take quite some time. I have heard of ways to update a specific ppa, however, the solutions don't work with a repository added through it's **deb** repository line.

Is there any way that I can choose to update only one non-ppa repository?